# GraphQL showing Value as null

Tags: node.js, graphql

I am learning GraphQL and I have two Object types.

Say, they look like this

Say, The book type looks like this

```
const BookType = new GraphQLObjectType({  
    name: 'Book',  
    fields: () => ({ 
        id: { type:  GraphQLID},
        name: { type: GraphQLString},
        genre: { type: GraphQLString }, 
        author: { 
            type: authorType,
            resolve(parents, args) {
               Author.findOne( 
                   {
                    name: parents.authorName
                   }, function(err, result) {
                       console.log(result)
                       return result
                   })
            }
        }

    })
})
```

and  Author Type looks like this

```
const authorType = new GraphQLObjectType({  
    name: 'author',  
    fields: () => ({ 
        id: { type:  GraphQLID},
        name: { type: GraphQLString},
        age: { type: GraphQLInt },
        books: {  
            type: new GraphQLList(BookType), 
            resolve(parent, args) {
            }
        }
    })
})
```

Now, I am adding data through Mutation (Not sharing it because I think it is irrelevant) and then run query in `graphql` to add data in Book Type. It correctly displays data for  name, genre, id but for authorType it is showing the data as null while the console].log results log something like this in console

```
//This is console log in terminal
{ age: 'none',
  _id: 5bcaf8904b31d50a2148b60d,
  name: 'George R Martin',
  __v: 0 }
```

THis is the query I am running in **graphiql**

```
mutation{
        addBooks( 
           name: "Game of Thrones",
           genre: "Science Friction", 
            authorName: "George R Martin"
            ) {
           name,
           genre,
           author {
           name
                }
              }
           }
```

My [entire schema is available here](https://github.com/irohitb/graphQL/blob/master/server/Schema/schema.js)

Can someone please-please help me figure out what could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A resolver must return either some value or a Promise that will resolve in a value -- if it doesn't the field being resolved will return null. So there's two things off about your code. One, you don't return either a value or a Promise. Two, you return something inside a callback, but that's not actually doing anything, since most libraries disregard the return value of a callback function anyway.

You can [wrap a callback in a Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Creating_a_Promise_around_an_old_callback_API), but that is going to be overkill here because mongoose already provides a way to return a Promise -- just omit the callback entirely.

```
resolve(parent, args) {
  return Author.findOne({name: parent.authorName)
}
```

Your mutation resolver works because you return the value returned by calling `save()`, which actually returns a Promise that will resolve to the value of the model instance being saved.